# Form php in email

Tags: php, html, email, newsletter

I create many newsletters. Is it possible to add a php form in email ? I explain, the customer open this email and on this email he see an input to add his email. Is it possible for me to keep the data ? For example we can imagine a simple input to subscribe newsletter.

Comment: While not entirely sure, then I'm fairy convinced that you cannot have forms in a email, simply because that the providers (gmail, yahoo, hotmail and so on), disables / disallows them for security reasons, that said, you can create a link that contains the users email and upon the user clicking said link you subscribe him to your newsletter.

Comment: i dont think you can be able to have vaues input on the mail, but you can attache a form-fielded pdf file where they can enter data and submit. You will have to handle the pdf submissions if you do it this way.

Comment: Ok I understand, how can I put the users email in my url?

Answer (score 0):

ya its possible... you need have a form in your email template and in form action you need to specify the php file which is there in your domain

E.x:

in your email template

```
<form method="GET" action="http://www.yourdomain.com/back_end_file.php">
   <label>Email id</label>
   <input type="text" name="email" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

In your server file i.e : http://www.yourdomain.com/back_end_file.php

```
<?php 
   echo $email = $_GET['email'];
?>
```

If it gives some cross domain issue then paste below code in first line in http://www.yourdomain.com/back_end_file.php this file

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

I hope this works...